# ink drawn mindmap

Tags: mind-mapping

I'm looking for any software on any platform which will let me draw a mind map directly on the surface of a screen (tablet, laptop with touch screen, whatever) using digital ink and have it turned into an actual mind map as I draw.  By this I mean that it must recognize where each node is and (ideally) OCR the text for that node while preserving the original handwriting.  It must also know how everything is connected and be able to shift nodes around as needed to make space, either automatically or manually, as well as let me edit what I have done.  It should also provide a way to export the map as some kind of hierarchical text document, for instance as HTML with UL/LI items.  Going to other direction to import would be nice too.

When I draw a mind map I don't necessarily adhere to the idea that there is a central idea and every subordinate node radiates outwards.  I just write a short bit of text in an area, then I draw a line to where I am going to write my next idea down, and so forth.  Part of this is due to the limitations of paper, because I don't always know where the nodes are going to fill in and I will run out of space if I don't try to pack nodes closer.  If I need to always draw outwards that is ok as long as I don't have a limitation on canvas size.  Being able to pan and zoom is a must. If I need to draw a rectangle around the text so it knows where the text is, that is okay too.